# How to unplug black friction pin connectors

Tags: technic, tools, disassembly

[Black friction pin without slots connectors](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4459) are common in older Technic sets. Note that these were quickly replaced by the [current version with slots](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2780) that is much easier to remove.

[image: Black friction pin without slots] vs [image: Black friction pin with slots]

Especially in older sets, it is not uncommon for these connectors to get completely stuck (as if glued) in bricks with holes. I have to resort to pincers and brute force. This typically results in the connector being damaged.

The [orange brick separator](http://cache.lego.com/e/dynamic/is/image/LEGO/630) is often not tough enough to do the job.

So, how can you separate these things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends in what type of beams the pin are mounted.

1. For studless Nicael's methode is the easiest. Otherwise you can use method 3
2. For studded beams you can use variation on this methode. take a axle of 6 or 8 long, 5 or 7 other beams and some plates. Stack the beam side by side and lock them together with the plates. Place the beam with the pin on top pin sticking out. Place the axle in the hole under which the pin is located. The axle will stick out 1 stud. Puch this on a hard surface that is allowed to be scratch / dented. This will remove also pins that are deformed.
3. If the pins are in other parts you often can move them to a studded beam by pushing the other end in a studded beam and putting in a minifig tool, like a broom, shovel or light saber blade.

Loose parts:

[image: Loose Parts]

Half assembled:

[image: Half assembled]

Axle placed:

[image: Axle placed]

Pushing pin out on table:

[image: Pushing pin out on table]

Switching to a beam:

[image: Switching to a beam]

Comment: My preferred method is the last one, but instead of using a Technic brick, I use a half width beam. The stick blocks the pin as it does with the full width brick, but once the stick is removed, the pin is very easy to pull out from the beam.

Answer (score 8):

Take your cross axle:

[image]

And push it into the hole where your pin connector had stuck

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a method I've tried. I've found it usually works better if you _don't_ push the cross axle perpendicularly (into the empty centre of the connector) as in the image. Rather aim for the black connector's outer edge from an angle (about 20 degrees). I agree that using cross axles is better than the orange brick separator.

Comment: @Gruber Looks like you are right! So it suits you or not?

Comment: This method is good, but it doesn't solve the hardest cases. One thing I'm going to try is to see if heating up the plastic in hot water is going to make things easier. Once separated, perhaps washing these black connectors can remove residues or filth that increase friction?

Comment: Indeed, LEGO used to recommend building a tool with two axles, an angle element and two bushes for just this event.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative 'pin-pusher' that I put together using as few pieces as I could (except for a few tiles to make it a bit more intersting).

[image]

The blue pin near the centre pushes pins out half way, just enough to remove the pins by hand and not to far for it to pop up out in the air.

[image]

The two tan axles help to align the Technic beam you are using, I find they are most useful when you are trying to remove a long row of pins on a single beam.

[image]

It is also quite good at [removing double pins with axle holes](https://i.imgur.com/SuyueR4.gif).

You *could* use some blue-tac to keep in in place but I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: I originally wanted to build a motorised version that would pins out of the holes almost like a drill press but I settled for something simpler and more functional.

Answer (score 4):

I have resorted to brute force in the past. By which I mean destructive removal of the pins. I use a Dremel tool with a 2mm drill bit or 3mm router bit to carve away at the pin until it disintegrates.

The new style pins sell for about 0.3c each on Bricklink, so if you're assembling a model it makes sense to just buy a pile of new pins and and use those instead. I use the pins as "stuff" for my construction models to work with, so I bought 10,000 pins in one hit for about $50 including delivery. It's just not worth putting the old pins into newly assembled models when it's so cheap to avoid the problem.

To actually remove the pins when they are stuck I use the approaches other people have given. When they fail I use olive oil as a lubricant (soak Lego in oil, wait). That's much easier if you can keep the end you're going to be pulling on out of the oil. Then use the "jam a bar into the end" technique to lock the pin into another Lego beam and pull it out. Usually twisting is required.

But I have to admit that I don't bother any more. I pull models apart, and pins that I can't get out with my fingers I just drill out. If I really have to I'll buy more old-style pins on Bricklink, but I have enough friends who buy second hand Lego and hate those pins that my supply is adequate. And I'm happy to give away the new style pins in exchange. Again, they cost me 0.5c/pin...

**The old pins are brilliant** if you're exhibiting a model and it has parts that tend to fall apart. Use the "stuck forever" pins and things don't fall off nearly as easily. It's legal, so you can still put the "Model is 100% unmodified Lego" sign on it whereas if you use glue you can't do that.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page on Bricklink where these new-style pins are sold? Thanks.

Comment: @Gruber I edited it into your question but the edit hasn't been approved yet. Sorry I didn't realise that: http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=2780  and click "lots for sale"

Answer (score 3):

I used to use the longest Technic axle I could find. The axle would be uncomfortable to use for dismantling large LEGO sets with hundreds of Technic pins as it would always dig into my palm when I forced the pins out.

[image]

If you push one or more [2x2 Round Bricks](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3941#T=C) into one end with a [2x2 Round Plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2654&name=Plate,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Rounded%20Bottom%20(Boat%20Stud)&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C) (with or without a rounded bottom) you have a nice handle which is a bit more comfortable to use.

[image]

When you place it down on a table it will never roll off onto the floor.

You can also change the colour of the handle to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has come up with a solution, but I do not understand whether I am missing something or if I actually know something others do not.

There is a LEGO piece made precisely for this. It is the Technic separator.

[image]

Comment: Never seen this screwdriver-like thing before. I could only find it for sale on [Amazon.co.uk](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LEGO-Technic-Separator-Connector-Brick/dp/B01I3051HA). Does it even work?

Comment: Yeah I have one myself and J have taken apart that green tractor 2jn1 technic from the early 2010s faster than you can imagine.

Answer (score -1):

I've used tweezers since I don't have an axle rod in hand.

Comment: Did they leave scuff marks on the pin?